# Python bottle with my own domain name

Tags: python, bottle

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"

run(host='http://domain', port=8080)
```

I'm trying to run this example with my own domain name, but no luck. I just get a 404. Does this have anything to do with those hosting it? 
I upload the python file to the web hosting service.

I tried uploading a simple html file. So the hosting should be live.

Answer (score 4):

Your hosting provider would need to launch the bottle app inside of their WSGI interface.  So they would need to also support python.  Or you need to host your own server and point the DNS to your own IP address and run it from there.